# Why Would One Light Fixture Work and Not Another?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I'm helping a friend install new outdoor garage lights, and I've run into a problem, which is a real head scratcher.  I'm hoping to get some ideas on how I can fix the issue.

A single indoor light switch controls the porch light, and two outdoor lights located on each side of the garage door.  I replaced the porch light with a new fixture, and that worked without any problem.  I then replaced both garage lights with identical light fixtures, after which they failed to work.  I checked, and there was electricity going to the bare wires, and I also checked that there was electricity going to the socket of the new fixture, however, the bulb would not light up for both fixtures.  I then reinstalled the old light fixtures, and they worked once again.  Both the old and new fixtures are stock outdoor lights from Home Depot.

I would appreciate any thoughts on why one light fixture would work, and another wouldn't, and any suggestions on fixing the problem.  Thank you!!

Comment: I assume you're using the same bulbs. It's possible that the tip contact on the light bulbs are slightly short or the tip contact in the new sockets are bent in a little bit so that these do not make contact. Try prying up the tip contact in the new sockets a little (with the power off, of course) and/or try a different bulb.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  The old fixture has built in LED lights so I'm only using the new bulbs with the new fixtures.  I will try to pry the base contact to see if that might work, although I suspect the issue might be due to the circuit.  An electrician tried to install a timer switch on that circuit (porch light and two exterior garage lights) with the old fixture in place and it wouldn't work.  That's when my friend thought to replace the old fixture with the new one, hoping that would resolve the issue, but it didn't...